# Power BI Flag Duplicates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

We have a problem where our source data can produce unexpected duplicates.  I want to create a process that will alert us when duplicates exist in tables.

I've used the approach to add the id to a table, then add the id again and count the id, then filter the visual for count > 1, which does a nice job of flagging the records duplicated.  However, I want to set up alerts, so I want to setup a calculation I can pin to a dashboard and set up and alert.  Struggling with setting up the right calculation.

My data looks like this:

[image]

So I would expect to see the ID 3 counted as duplicated.  Tried this but it errors out with "EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist".

```
Measure = IF(
          CALCULATE(
                 COUNTA(Table1[ID]),
                 FILTER(Table1, Table1[ID] = EARLIER(Table1[ID]))
           )>1, 
           0,
           1
     )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works as a calculated column, but `EARLIER` doesn't work quite the same in a measure since there is no inherent row context. If you want a measure, then try swapping out `EARLIER` for `MAX` or another aggregating function.

```
Measure = IF(
          CALCULATE(
                 COUNTA(Table1[ID]),
                 FILTER(Table1, Table1[ID] = MAX(Table1[ID]))
           )>1, 
           0,
           1
     )
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's some ideas using DAX. You could add a calculated column, to flag duplicates. Like this:

[image]

```
DuplicateFlag =
IF (
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( 'Table1', 'Table1'[ID] = EARLIER ( Table1[ID] ) ) )
        > 1,
    1,
    BLANK ()
)
```

Then you could use the following measure to calculate the number of duplicates and put it in a card visual.
`Number of Duplicates = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table1'[Name]),'Table1'[DuplicateFlag] = 1)`

And a measure like this to show the count of each duplicate in a matrix visual.
`count per duplicate = SUM([DuplicateFlag])`
[image]

Comment: Nice, I like the approach of the 2nd measure to accurately count the records duplicated instead of summing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a PowerQuery ("M" language) solution. Given than the values to check are in a list named "IdList", the code below returns a new list named "DupList" only with the duplicated values.

```
let
    IdList = {3,4,3,6,7,3,8,9,4,10,11},
    DupList = List.Distinct(List.Difference(IdList,List.Distinct(IdList)))
in
    DupList
```

In the example, DupList is equal to {3,4}, the only values that are duplicated. Now you can do with this new list whatever you want.

Probably you know it, but in "M" you can create a list just referencing the column name of a table: new_list = table_name[column_name]

Hope this helps

Comment: Interesting, hadn't thought about tackling in M.  I think I'd rather stay away from extra views though.  Thanks.